# AWS boto3 - Resource : lakeformation Function : batch_revoke_permissions - Represent ALL_TABLES

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-lake-formation

How do we represent "ALL_TABLES" in the lake_formation.batch_revoke_permissions function in boto3. Passing the argument as

{'Table':
{'DatabaseName': 'XXXX',
'Name': 'ALL_TABLES'
}
}

It fails with the below error.

'Error':
{
'ErrorCode': 'InvalidInputException',
'ErrorMessage': 'Table: ALL_TABLES not found.'
}

Comment: did you find an answer ?

Comment: Any luck with this issue

Comment: Hey, 2023 here and still the same problem, could  you solve it? I'm trying the command below but the documentation is terrible about the "wildcard" section:
aws lakeformation revoke-permissions --principal "{\"DataLakePrincipalIdentifier\": \"IAM_ALLOWED_PRINCIPALS\"}" --resource "{\"Table\": {\"DatabaseName\": \"sharepoint-bronze\", \"TableWildcard\": {}}}" --permissions "[\"ALL\"]" --region sa-east-1

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lakeformation.html#LakeFormation.Client.batch_revoke_permissions),

> Table (dict) -- The table for the resource. A table is a metadata
> definition that represents your data. You can Grant and Revoke table
> privileges to a principal.
>
> CatalogId (string) -- The identifier for the Data Catalog. By default,
> it is the account ID of the caller.
>
> DatabaseName (string) -- [REQUIRED] The name of the database for the
> table. Unique to a Data Catalog. A database is a set of associated
> table definitions organized into a logical group. You can Grant and
> Revoke database privileges to a principal.
>
> Name (string) -- The name of the table.
>
> TableWildcard (dict) -- A wildcard object representing every table
> under a database.
>
> At least one of TableResource$Name or TableResource$TableWildcard is
> required.

you should set the `'TableWildcard': {}` not the name.

Comment: And what is `TableWildcard` sire ?